# What's wrong with my buyToken function?

Tags: solidity, remix, solidity-0.5.x

Here is my solidity

```
interface IERC20 {
    function decimals() external view returns (uint8);
    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint);
    function balanceOf(address owner) external view returns (uint);
    function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint);

    function approve(address spender, uint value) external returns (bool);
    function transfer(address to, uint value) external returns (bool);
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint value) external returns (bool);
}

interface V2 {
    function decimals() external view returns (uint8);
    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint);
    function balanceOf(address owner) external view returns (uint);
    function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint);

    function approve(address spender, uint value) external returns (bool);
    function transfer(address to, uint value) external returns (bool);
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint value) external returns (bool);
}

pragma solidity ^0.5.17;
contract tokenSales {
    //string public name = "EthSwap Instant Exchange";
    
    // IERC20 public token;
    // V2 public rgp;
    address token = 0x87e9D87f85e80D79A77067A090F0748241892F74;
    address rgp = 0x153Eef8365e8F4ae62aC99b6C84520f81F572827;
    address owner;
    uint public price;
    
    uint256 public tokensSold;
    uint256 public decimals;
    
    event sold(address account, uint price, address token);
    
    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(
            msg.sender == owner,
            "RGP Token: Caller is not the Owner"
        );
        _;
    }

    constructor(uint _price) public payable{
        owner ==  msg.sender;
        price = _price;
 
        // SMC: 0xDA0bab807633f07f013f94DD0E6A4F96F8742B53
    }
    
    function() external payable{
        buyTokens();
        msg.value;
    }

    // Guards against integer overflows
    function mul(uint x, uint y) public pure returns (uint z) {
        require(y == 0 || (z = x * y) / y == x, 'ds-math-mul-overflow');
    }
        
        //uint tokens = contribution.mul(multiplier).div(TOKEN_PRICE);
        //tokenAllocations[investor] = tokenAllocations[investor].add(tokens);
        //tokensSold = tokensSold.add(tokens);
    
    function setBUSDCPrice(uint _price) public onlyOwner {
        price = _price;
    }
    
    function sendCollectedBUSDC (address payable _recipient)
        external
        onlyOwner
    {
        if (address(this).balance > 0) {
            _recipient.transfer(address(this).balance);
        }
    }

    function buyTokens() public payable {
        //CHECK FOR INPUT BALLANCE
        require(msg.value > 0, "RGP: INSUFFICIENT INPUT BALLANCE, YOU NEED TO SEND SOME BUSDT");
        
        //CALCULATE THE AMOUNT OF TOKEN TO PURCHASE
        uint256 tokensToBuy = mul(msg.value, uint256(10) ** IERC20(token).decimals()) / mul(price, uint256(10) ** V2(rgp).decimals());
        
        //ALLOWANCE FOR BOTH ADDRESS(THIS) AND MSG.SENDER
        V2(rgp).allowance(msg.sender, address(this));
        IERC20(token).allowance(address(this), msg.sender);
        
        //REQUIREMENT FOR ALLOWANCE
        tokensToBuy <= V2(rgp).allowance(address(this), msg.sender); // "RGP: CHECK THE TOKEN ALLOWANCE OF ADMIN";
        msg.value <= IERC20(token).allowance(msg.sender, address(this)); // "RGP: CHECK THE TOKEN BALANCE OF BUYER";
        
        //APPROVE FOR BOTH MSG.SENDER AND ADDRESS(THIS)
        V2(rgp).approve(msg.sender, tokensToBuy);
        IERC20(token).approve(address(this), msg.value);
        
        //TRANSFER FROM MSG.SENDER TO ADDRESS(THIS)
        IERC20(token).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), msg.value);
        
        //CHECK FOR BALANCE OF ADMIN
        uint256 rgpBalance = V2(rgp).balanceOf(address(this));
        
        //REQUIRE THAT THE BALANCE APPROVED IS GREATER THAN THE TOKENS TO BUY.
        require(rgpBalance >= tokensToBuy, "RGP: NOT ENOUGH TOKEN IN THE RESERVE");
        
        //TRANSFER FROM RGP TO MSG.SENDER
        V2(rgp).transferFrom(address(this), msg.sender, tokensToBuy);
        
        //REDUCE THE ALLOWANCE OF BOTH PARTIES
        IERC20(token).allowance(msg.sender, address(this)) + msg.value;
        V2(rgp).allowance(address(this), msg.sender) + tokensToBuy;
        
        //INCREASE THE ALLOWANCE OF BOTH PARTIES.
        IERC20(token).allowance(msg.sender, address(this)) + msg.value;
        V2(rgp).allowance(address(this), msg.sender) + tokensToBuy;
       
        // 
        tokensSold += msg.value; 
        emit sold(msg.sender, msg.value * price, address(token));
        
    }

    function endSale() public onlyOwner{
            // Send unsold tokens to the owner.
        require(V2(rgp).transfer(owner, address(this).balance), "RGP: Sales ended.");
        require(IERC20(token).transfer(owner, address(this).balance), "RGP: Sales ended.");
    
        msg.sender.transfer(address(this).balance);
    }
}
```

Deployed to ropsten ["HERE"](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x67855b3b5bce00fc88d7aad9ad878557feaaf8e5#code)

The token address ["TOKEN ADDRESS"](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/token/0x80278a0cf536e568a76425b67fb3931dca21535c).

Please I have been on this for some days trying to figure out what wrong but I couldn't I have checked related issues on this platform and others still the same, I actually taught it was stress so I decided to take some time out and came back still can't figure it out.

I test on remix it deducts ether from msg.sender and did not credit to smart contract address and as well msg.sender did not receive token.

Comment: I have intermediary knowledge of how it works, msg.sender approves the smart contract address to spent the _amount, and the smart contract transfer from msg.sender the _amount to its address and vice-verser, this was my taught please correct me if am wrong. i used on token because i want the smart contract to credit the msg.sender _amount * price.

Comment: This formula looks wrong  `_amount1 * 10 * decimals / _amount1 / price`, mathematically is equivalent to `10 * decimals / price`. Using approve+transferFrom doesn't work like you seems to be expecting. To accept ether payment you should use `msg.amount`. I'd suggest to read some tutorial or book.

Comment: yea, thanks for your prompt response.

Comment: i used this "uint256 tokensToBuy = mul(msg.value, uint256(10) ** rgp.decimals());" but nothing seems to happened that y i tried it foolishly. trying to transfer from contract address back to msg.sender address using the transfer keyword and will get back.

Comment: Sorry but there were other issues unless you fix them all it will not work. Did you understand why approve+transferFrom will work as expected? see https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/73714/erc20-approve-transferfrom-not-working for an explanation.

Comment: Thanks so much for your concerns @Ismael, i have edited the question please check to see if am not far from the track cause I still got an error to check and no swap took place.

Comment: Sorry, but you should learn solidity first. This line does nothing `V2(rgp).allowance(address(this), msg.sender) + tokensToBuy`. Also read again the link I posted, you still don't understand the mechanic of approve & transferFrom.

Comment: Thanks.
will fix it and get back to you.

Comment: @Ismael, really appreciate your support have been able to achieve that.
And it set and up 'n' running.

Comment: That is very good. You can write answer indicating how you fix the contract.

Comment: What If I want the users to buy my token using another unlisted token?
Lets say I want to sell my CrapToken to people paying using Crappytoken, both unlisted, both worthless. Is that poss

Comment: you want your user to buy a token that is not listed on the contract ?
@HiddenGemsss

Answer (score 1):

well coming back to answer my own question, it great and lovely thou.
my interface

```
interface IBEP20 {
    function decimals() external view returns (uint8);
    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint);
    function balanceOf(address owner) external view returns (uint);
    function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint);

    function approve(address spender, uint value) external returns (bool);
    function transfer(address to, uint value) external returns (bool);
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint value) external returns (bool);
}
```

and the function that handles the buy tokens

```
// Note: This function allows only purchases of "full" tokens, purchases of 0.1 tokens or 1.1 tokens for example are not possible
    function buyTokens(uint256 _tokenAmount) public {
        
        // Check if sale is active and user tries to buy atleast 1 token
        require(saleActive == true, "TOK: SALE HAS ENDED.");
        require(_tokenAmount >= 1, "TOK: BUY ATLEAST 1 TOKEN.");
        
        // Calculate the purchase cost
        uint256 cost = _tokenAmount * price;
        
        // Calculate the tokens _msgSender() will get (with decimals)
        uint256 tokensToGet = _tokenAmount * 10**18;
        
        // Transfer busd from _msgSender() to the contract
        // If it returns false/didn't work, the
        //  msg.sender may not have allowed the contract to spend busd or
        //  msg.sender or the contract may be frozen or
        //  msg.sender may not have enough busd to cover the transfer.
        require(IBEP20(busd).transferFrom(_msgSender(), address(this), cost), "TOK: TRANSFER OF BUSD FAILED!");
        
        // Transfer TOK to msg.sender
        // If it returns false/didn't work, the contract doesn't own enough tokens to cover the transfer
        require(IBEP20(tok).transfer(_msgSender(), tokensToGet), "TOK: CONTRACT DOES NOT HAVE ENOUGH TOKENS.");
        
        tokensSold += tokensToGet;
        emit Sale(_msgSender(), price, tokensToGet);
    }
```

@Ismael thanks for your contribution thus far