# transferFrom() not working

Tags: solidity, remix, erc-20

I have tried 2 days working on transerFrom. But not working so please help me.

I know we need to approve() first. Approve() and Allowance() seem to be fine.
I read this FAQ( https://forum.openzeppelin.com/t/transferfrom-always-reverts-with-revert-erc20-transfer-amount-exceeds-allowance/3993 ) but ... not working.
I read this one too. [ERC20 - Approve & TransferFrom not working](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/73714/erc20-approve-transferfrom-not-working?rq=1)

Here is what I did.

**What I want to do is for example,**

1. Tom send 10 BUSD to my contract X.
2. Contract X send TOKEN A to Tom.

**In Solidity(based on remix)**

1. Tom approve 10 BUSD
   ⇨ contractX.approve(Tom's Address, 10)
2. Tom send function buyToken
   ⇨ contractX.buyTokens(10)

**Here is my code**
`code`

```
function approveBUSD(address _spender, uint256 _value) public returns (bool) {
   return tokenB.approve(_spender, _value);
}

function buyTokens(uint256 amount) public payable {

uint256 allowance = tokenB.allowance(address(this), msg.sender);
require(allowance >= amount, "Check the token allowance");


tokenB.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this),amount);

emit BoughtTokens(msg.sender, amount); // log event onto the blockchain
```

I created two Solidity Contract. One is for TOKEN A issue. The other is this exchange program.

Token A transfer seems to be okay. But my contract can't accept BUSD. Even the BUSD approve seems fine..

Error message is

Internal JSON-RPC error. { "code": 3, "message": "execution reverted: insufficient allowance", "data":

So buyTokens(0) completely works!....

Please help me.
I will give you some tips...

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I have finally successed.

I stopeed to use remix.
I just used from web3.

haha,,,

[IERC20.approve(spender, amount) thinks the owner is also the contract](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/91063/ierc20-approvespender-amount-thinks-the-owner-is-also-the-contract)

thanks to this post

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. The correct process is first Tom should approve BUSD to contract x.

Tom approve 10 BUSD ⇨ BUSD.approve(ContractX, 10)